When using a servo with STM32F405RGT6 do I need to connect any CAP near the servo pins?
I am using a 9g servo motor and have connected two 100nF ceramic capacitors: one between 5V and GND for power supply decoupling, and one between the signal (SIG) and GND for signal integrity. Additionally, I’ve added a 470µF capacitor to smooth out voltage fluctuations and provide extra current during sudden spikes. Are these capacitors effective for my setup, or should I remove them?


The 100nF capacitor on the PWM signal will likely degrade the signal beyond recognition. At least that must be removed. Otherwise, the 100nF cap on supply is a good idea. The 470uF bulk being effective or not depends on many things, and may need further details to assess.

I took out the C18 cap. Also could I just let the bulk cap as it is and if it affects my servo just desolder it?
